# Vue, Axios with filter

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I'm really struggling with an API listing project. I have to show the results of an API call and then let the user to search for specific values. The listed result is already in v-for so I can't filter it again. Unfortunately, there's no other way than sending one more axios call by click on the search button and filter the response. And the API is super complicated, not possible just to attach the `+this.searchedValue` because it won't find it, it's a nested array. Is it possible like that? Also, I'm very open to hear any other solutions.

**The following code already shows the list but with the search bar I'd like to have a new list about the searched value.**

```
<ul>
  <li @click="select(content.id)" 
  v-for="(content,id) in contents" 
  :key="id"
  >
    <h4> {{ content.department.label }} </h4>
    <p> {{ content.location.city }} </p>
  </li>
</ul>

 mounted() {
      axios.get('https://api/')
                        .then(response => {
                            this.contents = response.data.content;
                        })
    }
```

**I have already tried to loop in the filter, like this way but then the list doesn't appear:**

```
 computed: {
  Filter: function(){
            return this.contents.filter((content) => {
               return content.match(this.filter);
            });
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place filter inside of computed property

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" v-model="search" />
<li v-for="(item, index) in filteredList">
 {{item}}
</li>


data() {
    return {
        search: ''
    }
},
computed() {
    filteredList() {
        let self = this
        this.contents.filter(item => {
            return item.department.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it says: "Expected to return a value in "filteredList" computed property". But if I have this filteredList, then it won't show the original list at all. :(

Comment: .filter method returns array so when search  == ' ' then filteredList should return full list. When you start searching in search input the array will return only search items.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It worked, only that the last line is: return content.department.label.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())